# UIImagePickerController overlay view using React Native components

Tags: ios, react-native, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to define a `UIImagePickerController` overlay view using React Native components. I'm setting up to add a new option to Marc Shilling fabulous [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker). I want the `ImagePickerManager.launchCamera` function to take a `<View>` and children as one of its parameters, render it, and pass that to `UIImagePickerController.cameraOverlayView`. I got this far:

In ImagePickerManager.m:

```
NSNumber *viewTag = [self.options valueForKey:@"overlayNode"];
if (![viewTag isEqual:[NSNull null]] && viewTag != 0) {
    UIView *view = [_bridge.uiManager viewForReactTag:viewTag];
    [self.picker setCameraOverlayView:view];
}
```

But this requires me to do some contortions on the JS side in order to get a component instance.

```
React.createClass({
    render: function() { 
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._showCamera}><Text>Camera</Text></TouchableHighlight>
                <View ref="foo"><Text>On top of the camera!</Text></View>
            </View>
        );
    },
    _showCamera: function() {
        var options = {
            overlayNode: React.findNodeHandle(this.refs.foo),
        };
        ImagePickerManager.launchCamera(options, (response)  => {

        });
    }
});
```

I get a redbox if I try to say `overlayNode: React.findNodeHandle(<View ref="foo"><Text>On top of the camera!</Text></View>)`.

I experimented a bit with creating a new `RCTRootView` and registering the overlay via `AppRegistry.registerComponent` but I didn't see anything actually render on the screen.

```
NSString *overlayRootName = [self.options valueForKey:@"overlayComponentName"];
if (![overlayRootName isEqual:[NSNull null]] && overlayRootName.length != 0) {
    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:self.bridge moduleName:overlayRootName initialProperties:nil];
    [self.picker setCameraOverlayView:rootView];
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter solution (declaring an alternative `RCTRootView`) ended up being the one that worked for me. The problem I was having was that for some reason the bridge that I got in the `ImagePickerManager` from adding `@synthesize bridge = _bridge;` was not rendering anything when used in `initWithBridge`.

Instead, I added a field to my `AppDelegate` exposing the bridge created in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` much like what was done [in this hybrid app example](https://github.com/dsibiski/react-native-hybrid-app-examples/blob/master/iOS/RNEmbeddedAppExample/AppDelegate.h). When I use *that* bridge in `initWithBridge`, the overlay renders on the screen. Also made sure to explicitly set `rootView.frame` and `rootView.backgroundColor` to transparent.

[image: Screenshot of UIImagePicker with React Native Overlay]